# How can i use ng-repeat inside ng-repeat but inner ng-repeat should print one value of an array at a time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the code below, `mydt` data is coming from a json and `chkdur` data is coming from a different array. I want to print the `mydt` and `chkdur` values simultaneously...

**My Code**

```
<tr ng-repeat="sdetail in mydt">
    <td>{{sdetail.pmsg}}</td>
    <td>{{sdetail.displaytime}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="st in chkdur">{{st}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you clarify more, what kind of exact output you want?

Comment: I want output like: <td>Hello</td><td>12:00</td><td>Active</td> <td>Hello</td><td>12:00</td><td>Expired</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$index` to print respective json data from second array

```
<tr ng-repeat="sdetail in mydt">
                    <td>{{sdetail.pmsg}}</td>
                    <td>{{sdetail.displaytime}}</td>
                    <td>{{chkdur[$index]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<tr ng-repeat="(pIndex, sdetail) in mydt">
    <td>{{sdetail.pmsg}}</td>
    <td>{{sdetail.displaytime}}</td>
    <td >{{chkdur[pIndex]}}</td>
</tr>
```